# How to Fix Settings in Oracle - Text is Reformatting When Hitting Return

Tags: oracle

I have been having an issue in Oracle where anytime I hit Enter at the end of a line of code the entire line will reformat as Title Case (the first letter of each thing is capitalized and the rest is lowercase). Here's a very short example of what I mean.

Original:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     col1
    ,col2 AS Test2
    ,CASE WHEN col3 = 'ABC' THEN 'DEF'
        END AS Test3
```

If I go to the end of each line in the code above and hit Enter, this is what it will look like:

```
Select Distinct
     Col1
    ,Col2 As Test2
    ,Case When Col3 = 'ABC' Then 'DEF'
        End As Test3
```

This happens both when I am editing existing lines as well as adding in new ones.

I haven't been able to find a solution online and can't find anything related to this in the Preferences. Thanks for the help!

Comment: "Oracle" is a database server that has no UI where you can enter SQL, let alone any formatting features. This is done by the SQL client tool you are using. Which one is that? Oracle SQL Developer maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*IF* we are talking about SQL Developer, then

Tools => Preferences => Code Editor => Format

and turn off the "Autoformat ..." check box at the top of the preferences panel.

[image]